# Java : ObjectInputStream, 3 messages sent, only 2 received

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking, serialization

Welcome to the fabulous world of networks. I discovered my passion. :)
However I have a very strange behavior in my app, and I would need your help to solve this one.

I made a simple server-client app.
The sending Thread :

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(message);
            objectOutputStream.flush();

        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}).start();
```

The receiving Thread :

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
                Message message = (Message) objectInputStream.readObject();
                Log.i("DEBUG", message);
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}).start();
```

It works just fine, however if I **send simultaneously 3 messages**, my receiving thread **only receives the 2 first ones**. It does not matter if I change the order. The third is always lost.

I think it's a buffer size problem. How can I deal with that? Thank you. :)

Comment: You should use the same object streams for the life of the socket, and you need some synchronization on the socket if you're going to send or receive multi-threaded.

Comment: Thank you for your help @EJP. Do you know where I can find an example of this structure?

Answer (score -1):

BufferedReader buffers the input, just as the name says. This means that it reads from the input source into a buffer before passing it onto you. The buffer size here refers to the number of bytes it buffers.

```
ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream(), size));
```

you can use size of `BufferedInputStream` and the reading of the `buffer` is slow so send the data with some delay
`

Comment: He isn't using `BufferedReader`. Final sentence is meaningless.